# How to remove amp word from center of url

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite, 301-redirect, url

I removed Amp Module from our site and I need to remove amp word from center of all of urls.

Using Nginx Web server
for example :

```
mysite.com/shirt/nike?amp=1&product_list_dir=asc&product_list_order=off
```

should be:

```
mysite.com/shirt/nike?&product_list_dir=asc&product_list_order=off
```

or

```
mysite.com/shoes/nike?amp=1&product_list_dir=asc&product_list_order=off
```

should be :

```
mysite.com/shoes/nike?&product_list_dir=asc&product_list_order=off
```

Please Help Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work.

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        if ($args ~* (.*)(\?|&)amp=1(&.*|$)) {
            set $args $1$2;
        }
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$1$is_args$args last;
    }

    # ... other server configuration ...
}
```

you have to edit your virtual host on your Nginx.
It should be in this directory...

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com
```

In the configuration above, you should first check if the query string contains the "amp=1" parameter using a regular expression in the if block. If it does, we use the set directive to remove that parameter from the query string. Then, we use the rewrite directive to rewrite the URL without the "amp=1" parameter. This configuration should work for the examples you provided.

Then test your Nginx config that have no confilict

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If there was no conflict then just soft reload your Nginx.

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hi thank you for your solution i tried but doesn`t works

Comment: Internal error 500 server

Comment: @peymanpeymani you have to customize the configuration, maybe the root directory in your case is different, you also need to check your nginx log to fine the what is wrong.

Comment: @peymanpeymaniyou can provide more detail like logs in case you need more help.